# How to make a new ArrayList with everything inside of it duplicated?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a method that takes an ArrayList and double everything inside of it. For example, if an ArrayList words stores ["hello", "there"] it should output ["Hello", "Hello", "there", "there"]. I already made a method that I think should work but it doesnt. Can anyone tell me where I got it wrong? I would very much appreciate it! My code is down below.

```
public ArrayList<String> doubleList(ArrayList<String> words) {
    ArrayList<String> newWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        newWords.add(words.get(i));
        newWords.add(words.get(i));
    }
    return newWords;
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with your method?

Comment: According to the website I am practicing on, I am only outputting what is on the ArrayList called words. I am not duplicating any

Comment: @Niko don't believe everything you see on the web.

Comment: Perhaps it is expecting the elements to be added to the input list, not in a new list?

Comment: Voting to close, can not be reproduced. (Create a [mcve])

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried to run your method and it works perfectly.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("a");
        words.add("b");
        words.add("c");
        ArrayList<String> doubledList = doubleList(words);
        System.out.println(doubledList);
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> doubleList(ArrayList<String> words) {
        ArrayList<String> newWords = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            newWords.add(words.get(i));
            newWords.add(words.get(i));
        }
        return newWords;
    }
}
```

I got the result as below:

> [a, a, b, b, c, c]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your website might not like that you are creating new storage. How about we try to make some changes in place, like this?

```
public ArrayList<String> doubleList(ArrayList<String> words) {
    int currWordsSize = words.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < currWordsSize; i++) {
        int indexOfInterest = 2*i;
        String currWord = words.get(indexOfInterest);
        words.add(indexOfInterest+1, currWord);
    }
    return words;
}
```